# How to pass and get data from Ajax to PHP using Data-tables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to use Data-tables but I need to pass a value from Ajax to PHP file.

the Ajax part is like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var oTable =
            $('#user-list').DataTable({
                "serverSide": true,

                "ajax": {
                    "url": "assets/server_processing_reminders.php",
                    "data": {
                        "CurrentFlag": 1
                    }
                },

                "columnDefs": [{
                    "width": "6%",
                    "targets": 0
                }],


                "order": [
                    [1, "asc"]
                ]

            });


    });
</script>
```

on the server side Im trying to get the variable "CurrentFlag" using:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["CurrentFlag"])){
    $cf = $_GET["CurrentFlag"];
}

echo $cf;
```

but the php file is not printing out the value send.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Try $_REQUEST["CurrentFlag"];

Comment: Jquery server side datatable only work with ajax "POST" method

Comment: http://phppot.com/php/datatables-server-side-processing-using-php-with-mysql/

Comment: You need to provide request type as "GET" as shown here :-


"ajax" : {
                 "url": "assets/server_processing_reminders.php", 
                 type: "GET",
                 "data": {
                            "CurrentFlag": 1
                        }
                }

Comment: @SanalS that seems to work!

Comment: I have posted it as an answer, You Can mark it as your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` like this :

```
 if(isset($_REQUEST["CurrentFlag"]))
  {
    $cf = $_REQUEST["CurrentFlag"];

   }

   echo $cf;
```

**OR**

If you want print data using `$_GET` method please add  `type:GET` under ajax call

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide request type as `GET` as shown here.

```
"ajax" : { 
    "url": "assets/server_processing_reminders.php", 
    type: "GET", 
    "data": { 
            "CurrentFlag": 1 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery for better code and results.

Learn Ajax using this link :

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp